# error while using array in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main() //task 10
{
    int num[9], i, counter = 0, minNum, maxNum = 0, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
        if (num[i] > maxNum)
        {
            maxNum = num[i];
            minNum = maxNum;
        }
        else if (num[i] < minNum)
            minNum = num[i];
        sum += num[i];
    }
    printf("minNum: %d, maxNum: %d\nThe average is:%d\n", minNum, maxNum, sum / 10);
    return 0;
}
```

While trying to run this program i get this error:
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'num' was corrupted.
I would like to know what is wrong with my array.

Comment: `int num[9]` --> `int num[10]`. Also `minNum = maxNum;` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using code below you will read the array out of bounds

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
```

you can only access elements from 0 up to and including 8 in this case. Change to `i < 9`.

PS. There maybe other flaws in the logic (check some comments). This one here is also tricky

```
if (num[i] < minNum)
```

`minNum` is not initialized, so if above condition is evaluated in loop first, you will get undefined behaviour due to reading uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 2):

Change `<=9` in the for loop at the numbering starts at zero. Use `<9` instead